# IQueryable.FirstOrDefault() and IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() return different values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
var v1 = _questionRepository.GetQuery().Where(q =>
                    q.EvaluationGroupId == evaluationGroupId &&
                    ((q.TopicValue == questionTopic &&
                    q.Index > currentQuestionIndex) ||
                     (q.TopicValue > (questionTopic) &&
                     q.Index >= 0 && q.Id != currentQuestionIndex)))
                     .OrderBy(q => q.Index).OrderBy(a => a.TopicValue).FirstOrDefault();

   var v2 = _questionRepository.GetQuery().Where(q =>
                    q.EvaluationGroupId == evaluationGroupId &&
                    ((q.TopicValue == questionTopic &&
                    q.Index > currentQuestionIndex) ||
                     (q.TopicValue > (questionTopic) &&
                     q.Index >= 0 && q.Id != currentQuestionIndex)))
                     .OrderBy(q => q.Index).OrderBy(a => a.TopicValue).ToList().FirstOrDefault()
```

*v1   **!=**  v2* **ENTITIES DIFFERENT**  How is it possible? (Data in db the same)

repository operate with EF entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was that it used OrderBy().OrderBy instead OrderBy().ThenBy(). So problem is there. if change source code to OrderBy().ThenBy() then all work correct.

Answer (score 6):

The != operator compares references, not data. They might be returning the same values, but != doesn't compare values, it compares object references to the memory heap (pointers).

Since your v2 query calls .ToList(), it's actually creating a copy of the results and putting them in a different variable. Hence, v2 points to the results of an executed query, whereas v1 points to an executable query. These are totally different objects entirely.

Comment: "The != operator compares references, not data."  In this case, yes.  Worth mentioning that this is not necessarily true if you override .Equals().